# How to convert a list of tuples into a single string

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, where all emlements in the tuples are strings. It could look like this:

```
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]
```

I want to convert this to a string so it would look like 'a b c d e'. I can use ' '.join( ... ) but I'm unsure of what argument I should use.

Answer (score 5):

You can flatten the list, then use join:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ' '.join(itertools.chain(*my_list))
'a b c d e'
```

or with list comprehension:

```
>>> ' '.join([i for sub in my_list for i in sub])
'a b c d e'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]
>>> ' '.join(' '.join(i) for i in my_list)
'a b c d e'
```

Comment: When using `str.join` you should use a list comprehension, not a generator expression. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3005188).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension which will iterate over the tuples and then iterate over each tuple, returning the item for joining.

```
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]

s = ' '.join([item for tup in my_list for item in tup])
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
a = []
for tup in my_list:
    for item in tup:
        a.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]

L = []

for x in my_list:
    L.extend(x) 

print ' '.join(L)


output:
'a b c d e'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]
print "".join(["".join(list(x)) for x in my_list])
```

Try this.

Comment: Converting tuple to list in the inner join in not required.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is the **best one liner solution** to your question :-

```
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e')]
s = ' '.join([elem for item in my_list for elem in item])
```